# Pandas dataframe time series: get maximum column value in a given row (date) range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe time series (index is a date&time, not an integer) of stock price and I am trying to find the max value of column 'A' in the last 200 rows of the df so I tried:

```
    maxofAinlast200rows = df.loc[-201:-1,'A'].max()
```

It returns:

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

I understand the error, but I am not sure how to get around it easily. In my case, the last row would be today's date, and the initial row for the calculation would be the date 200 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.loc` you need to use the exact indexes, not integer, else you need to use `.iloc`. So what you need to do is the following:

```py
maxofAinlast200rows = df.iloc[-201:-1].A.max()
```